# How do I stop windows from turning off sound when the screen enters power-saving?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I don't know if this is a problem unique to Windows 10, or if it started in 8, but every computer I have that runs Windows 10 will mute the audio when the screen shuts off. I know it's not entering sleep mode, as everything keeps running, including the amount of time spent playing music. (ie if the monitor goes into power-saving mode, and 2 minutes later I move the mouse, the song will have progressed by 2 minutes, but no sound is played while the monitor is off) I have a laptop, a tablet, and a desktop all running Windows 10, and all of them do this, even when external speakers are hooked up, in the case of the laptop and tablet. Does anyone know how to change this behavior? I want the audio to keep playing when the screen turns off. (I doubt it matters, but just in case, the laptop is an HP Envy m6, the tablet is a Winbook tw801, and the desktop is custom built with an Athlon 5350 cpu and an ASRock AM1H-ITX motherboard. The laptop and tablet are running Windows 10 Home, and the desktop Windows 10 Pro)